# Creating SQL table from variable with spaces in the name

Tags: sql, vb.net, filenames, space

I am trying to create an SQL table using VB.net, using a variable.

The only issue is that the table name is a derivation of a filename and that can sometimes contain space.

Below is an example of my code:

```
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim FileNameOnly As String

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\***\***\***"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    End If
    strFileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName
    If strFileName <> "" Then

        FileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = FileNameOnly

Using con = New SqlConnection("server=***\SQLEXPRESS; database=***Billing; integrated security=yes")
            Using cmda = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE '" + FileNameOnly + "' (CallType VarChar(30),ChargeCode VarChar(30),Destination VarChar(30),TariffUsed VarChar(30),Peak Float,OffPeak Float,Weekend Float,Setup Float,MinimumCharge Float,ChargeCap INT,InitialUnits INT,InitialCharge INT,InitialPeak INT,InitialOffPeak INT,InitialWeekend INT,BillingUnit INT,MinimumUnits INT,RateType VarChar(30));", con)
                con.Open()
                cmda.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
```

...this is the error I get

"Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'FFA68878 CPS rates'."

The safe filename is "FFA68878 CPS rates"

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Using variable name with spaces or other non alphanumeric characters is not a good practice. You will have problems. A lot of problems. Filenames can contain periods and other punctuation that RDBMS do not accept in column names. And you will have to quote all column names because of what they may contain. Are you sure you have no other way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way to remove the spaces from the filename - I wonder If that would be a better option?

Comment: Certainly there is a way in vb.net... but it won't solve your problem as then you will not be able to distinguish between "a b c" and "abc". Filenames are just not good for column names. You'll have problems... sooner or later... a lot of problems.

Comment: It is not a column name, but a table name - I know the rough format of the filenames that will be supplied and having similar filenames, other than spaces is not going to be an issue. In saying that I would ideally like to add with the spaces present. I have tested in SQL Studio and for the filenames in question it works fine. What would be the correct VB syntax if I want to go down that route? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your table and column name (with spaces) within square brackets like

```
Using cmda = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE [" + FileNameOnly + "] (CallType . . .RateType VarChar(30));", con)
```

Note the **. . .[" + FileNameOnly + "]. . .** above.